# Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid with Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, toolkit

I've searched the web for some introductory tutorial about the Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com) and custom attributes but didn't find. I've also downloaded the source code with the samples inside but that didn't help either. I'm a beginner with WPF so i might be missing something simple here. What i want to do is to create a simple Property Grid with some custom attributes. Does someone have a code snippet of something simple like a Property Grid with two attributes like `Name` and `Age` that are associated with some class like `Person`.  I've already tried the snippet that they provide in the PropertyGrid documentation page on Codeplex but i couldn't get it to work. I've managed to put the Property Grid appear on the UI, but that's all, no custom attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your `Name`, `Age` are string/int types.. So if you assign your object as `SelectedObject` to PropertyGrid- it must do just fine. For example here is my code where i show application settings as property grid to the user:
*wpf*:

```
   <extToolkit:PropertyGrid
            Name="PropertyPanel"
            IsManipulationEnabled="True"></extToolkit:PropertyGrid>
```

*codebehind*:

```
 PropertyPanel.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

PopertyGrid assigns templates automatically, depending on property type.